# Dynamicly adding content to the head element in vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to dynamicly adding content to the DOM head element in vaadin. I know that there is the `AppShellConfigurator` but i need the current path as context.

I also found `Page.addDynamicImport()` but i can't find any documentation about it.

So i wonder if there is any API to do this other than executing javascript for it.

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. You mean the HTML <head>?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes. I want to add dynamicly a link to a manifest to head based on the current url. In the configurePage() Method of AppShellConfigurator no URL is present.

Comment: There is no API because it's a SPA so the shell (index.html) stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

If your application happens to be typical Spring Boot based Vaadin app, you should be able to get the context path via ServletContext

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements AppShellConfigurator {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext context;
    
    private String contextPath;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configurePage(AppShellSettings settings) {
        contextPath = context.getContextPath();
        System.out.println("Context: "+contextPath);       
        ...      
    }
}
```